# Can anyone explain the difference between Uuid::generate and DB::generateKey?

Tags: darklang-beta

Without thinking too hard about it I created a column of type [UUID] and successfully stored "strings" (as noted in the documentation, and generally referred to as a separate type altogether) returned from DB::generateKey in it.

Feels like I've done something I shouldn't have.

Can anyone share some light on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly they return different types.
For clarity, `DB::generateKey` is equivalent to `Uuid::generate |> toString`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [standard library docs](https://ops-documentation.builtwithdark.com/?pretty=1), it's the return type.

```
Uuid::generate() -> UUID
Generate a new UUID v4 according to RFC 4122

DB::generateKey() -> Str
Returns a random key suitable for use as a DB key
```

I believe the `UUID` type is a bitstring representation, that is, a specific sequence of bits in memory.

Whereas the `Str` type is a string representation of a UUID.